# Menu Positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working on simple HTML/CSS site, using a horizontal floated CSS menu. The problem i have is i cant figure out how to alter the positioning of the menu. Its currently at the top, i know that the function top: x px or bottom: x px are used to move anything up and down from top or bottom, but when i use either the menu still stays at the top? Can floated menu's anywhere other than at the top, as this limits what i can do with my site?

Comment: Could you please post an example of the html you have for your menu, and the related CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the "position" style to "relative" for your floated element.

an example:

```
.floatedElement
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your HTML and CSS look like, but if you have a wrapper around the menu you can position the wrapper anywhere on your page.

To help you with the how to do that, check out this great tutorial on [CSS positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)...

Answer (score 1):

Top, bottom, left, right all work with relative or absolute positioning.

If you aren't using these and have a floated container (eg: float:left;), as I tend to, then you can use margin or padding settings to position the element.

Comment: I did a few trials of this and found that if an element is floating you can add relative positioning to get left and top working. Keeps box model issues to a minimum too =)